# Getting previous nodes from XML using AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, loops

Hi all I am using actionscript to bring in data from an XML file. I can cycle through the XML file using next and back buttons in AS3. This information is being loaded into dynamic text boxes. I am struggling **looping** through the xml file when the end of the xml file is reached! For example when I click the next button in as3 the next venue is shown however when the the last venue is shown I want the button to cycle back to the beginning of the XML file if this makes sense.

I have already configured the AS3 so it cycles back to the beginning with the next button however I am struggling loading the last venue when the Previous button is clicked.

```
function nextVenue(e:Event) {
    //Looks at length cycles to next venue
    if (currentVenue < myXML.venue.length()) {
        //cycle through venues when next_btn is clicked
        currentVenue +=length; 
    } else {
        //loop to beginning
        (currentVenue =length) 
    }
    //Output to title textbox
    myTextBoxTitle.text = myXML.venue.name[currentVenue -1] ;

    //Output to description textbox
    myTextBoxDes.text = myXML.venue.description[currentVenue -1];
}

//previous event function / when back button is clicked
function prevVenue(e:Event) {    
    if (currentVenue >length) {
        currentVenue -=length; //cycle back through venue when prev_btn is clicked -1
    }  
    //Output to title textbox
    myTextBoxTitle.text = myXML.venue.name[currentVenue -1];

    //Output to description textbox
    myTextBoxDes.text = myXML.venue.description[currentVenue -1] 
 }
```

XML FILE

http://pastebin.com/gzc4t2WR

Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: Could please update your XML Structure so only we can help out.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
 if (currentVenue < myXML.venue.length()) {
    //cycle through venues when next_btn is clicked
    currentVenue +=length; 
  } else {
    //loop to beginning
    (currentVenue =length) 
  }
```

You're setting the currentVenue to the current length - but your comment says loop to beginning. If that is the case then you need to reset the currentVenue to 0 - what is length?

** New Code **

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class testing extends Sprite
{

    public var switch1:String = 'a';
    public var switch2:String = "3";
    public var myXML:XML;

    public var nextButton:Sprite;
    public var prevButton:Sprite;
    public var currentVenue:int;

    public var myTextTitle:TextField;
    public var myTextDes:TextField;

    public function testing() {

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this.init);
        var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("./test.xml"));
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.processXML);
    }

    public function init(e:Event):void {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this.init);
        this.currentVenue = 0;=
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
        this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight);
        this.graphics.endFill();

        this.nextButton = this.createSpriteButton("next");
        this.addChild(this.nextButton);
        this.nextButton.x = 10;
        this.nextButton.y = 10;

        this.prevButton = this.createSpriteButton("prev");
        this.addChild(this.prevButton);
        this.prevButton.x = 100;
        this.prevButton.y = 10;

        this.myTextTitle = new TextField();
        this.addChild(this.myTextTitle);
        this.myTextTitle.background = true;
        this.myTextTitle.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;
        this.myTextTitle.text = "Title: ";
        this.myTextTitle.x = 10;
        this.myTextTitle.y = 40;
        this.myTextTitle.width = 100;
        this.myTextTitle.height = 20;

        this.myTextDes = new TextField();
        this.addChild(this.myTextDes);
        this.myTextDes.background = true;
        this.myTextDes.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;
        this.myTextDes.text = "Des: ";
        this.myTextDes.x = 10;
        this.myTextDes.y = 70;
        this.myTextDes.width = 100;
        this.myTextDes.height = 20;

        this.nextButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.nextVenue);
        this.prevButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.prevVenue);
    }

    private function createSpriteButton(btnName:String):Sprite {
        var sBtn:Sprite = new Sprite();
        sBtn.name = btnName;
        sBtn.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        sBtn.graphics.drawRoundRect(0,0,80,20,5);
        var sBtnTF:TextField = new TextField();
        sBtn.addChild(sBtnTF);
        sBtnTF.text = btnName;
        sBtnTF.x = 5;
        sBtnTF.y = 3;
        sBtnTF.selectable = false;
        sBtn.alpha = .5;

        sBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(e:Event):void { sBtn.alpha = 1 });
        sBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, function(e:Event):void { sBtn.alpha = .5 });

        return sBtn;
    }

    private function processXML(e:Event):void {
        this.myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
        this.updateData();
    }

    private function updateData():void {
        this.myTextTitle.text = "Title: " + this.myXML.venue.name[currentVenue];
        this.myTextDes.text = "Des: " + this.myXML.venue.description[currentVenue];
    }

    private function nextVenue(e:Event):void {
        this.updateCurrentVenue(1);
        this.updateData();
    }

    private function prevVenue(e:Event):void {
        this.updateCurrentVenue(-1);
        this.updateData();
    }

    private function updateCurrentVenue(step:int):void {
        if(step > 0) {
            this.currentVenue < this.myXML.venue.length()-1 ? this.currentVenue++ : this.currentVenue = 0;
        } else {
            this.currentVenue != 0 ? this.currentVenue-- : this.currentVenue = this.myXML.venue.length()-1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thankyou for that! how would I go about getting the last venue when the prev button is clicked?

Comment: I can do this using currentVenue +=4; but I dont want my code to be dynamic in case I add more information to the XML file

Comment: when you display the venue name and description you're subtracting 1 from it. Try not to use that, but the actual currentVenue value.  For Previoius you just need to check to make sure the currentVenue isn't already 0, then use the -1.  But you should update the currentVenue and not use a modified index in the call

Comment: When using what you suggested I get this Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.

Comment: Why do you subtract 1 from the currentVenue?

Comment: I've been working on XML again after switching to JSON years ago - had to go back a figure a few things out but I've added some code that compiles and runs through the list - next and prev with wrapping.